# Adobe CQ / AEM akka integration

Tags: scala, osgi, akka, apache-felix, aem

I was playing around adobe cq and scala and as a result I was able to write scala service and deploy it to osgi container.

Afterwards I tried to integrate akka with following [tutorial](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/additional/osgi.html) and I get the following error

```
28.08.2014 12:23:45.656 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1409217825642] POST /system/console/bundles/352 HTTP/1.1] cqse-httpservice %bundles.pluginTitle: Cannot start (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.aem.twitter-aem [352].) org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Activator start error in bundle com.aem.twitter-aem [352].
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2184)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2052)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.core.BundlesServlet.doPost(BundlesServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:526)
    at org.apache.felix.webconsole.internal.servlet.OsgiManager.service(OsgiManager.java:450)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.osgi.JaxRsFilter.doFilter(JaxRsFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:321)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:340)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:383)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:335)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler$TaskQueue
    at akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.<init>(Scheduler.scala:298)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$2.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:78)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:191)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:73)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess$$anonfun$createInstanceFor$3.apply(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:230)
    at akka.actor.ReflectiveDynamicAccess.createInstanceFor(DynamicAccess.scala:84)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.createScheduler(ActorSystem.scala:675)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(ActorSystem.scala:575)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141)
    at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:125)
    at akka.osgi.OsgiActorSystemFactory.createActorSystem(OsgiActorSystemFactory.scala:33)
    at akka.osgi.ActorSystemActivator.start(ActorSystemActivator.scala:42)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2134)
    ... 54 more
```

It throws NoClassDefFoundError, but I can see that class in Scheduler.scala file

Comment: Sometimes a class is already part of the osgi framework bundle but not exported/visible. You could try to add the package which causes problems to the "org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation" in the "sling.properties"

Answer (score 0):

If adding `sun.misc` to `org.osgi.framework.bootdelegation` in `sling.properties` did not work for you, try adding the following OSGI fragment artifact as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.livesense</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.liveSense.fragment.sun.misc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

> This bundle extends the System Bundle export list with the sun.misc package such that OSGi bundles may refer to Sun's misc implementation without the OSGi framework itself to provide it in a non-portable way.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.livesense/org.liveSense.fragment.sun.misc

In other words, the fragment attaches to the System Bundle and modifies the exports, such that `sun.misc` packages are exposed for import by other bundles.  By default, the framework bundle only exports the `java.*` and `javax.*` packages.  The `sun.misc` packages are necessary for certain dynamic and low-level language features in Groovy/Scala/Akka.